# Check50 Errros: Not passing " handles most basic words properly" and "handles substrings properly" tests. Check50 also can't check for a memory error

Tags: cs50, spell-checking

I am working on Pset5 Speller. I've managed to get all my errors down to three, but I cannot figure out how to fix my program so that it handles most basic words and handles substrings. I have run debugger, but it doesn't really help. I have also run valgrind and it says that no memory leaks are possible. I think the problem maybe my check function or hash function, so I have changed them a few times but I still get the same check50 results. The sumbit50 link:
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/57b8af186bcdadea0b585f0785ef47a5cf317b99 says that check50 only ever finds 1 word in the dictionary and identifies all words as misspelled. I really am not quite sure what the problem is. Can someone help me please? Here are my checks and hash functions. Thank you!!!

```
    // Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // hash function created by Deliberate Think on Youtube
    int hash_key = 0;
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(word[i]))
        {
            n = word[i] - 'a' + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            n = 27;
        }
        hash_key = ((hash_key << 3) + n) % N;
    }
    return hash_key;
}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // create an array to store words, then copy words from table to compare
    int n = strlen(word);
    char wordcheck[LENGTH + 1];
    strcpy(wordcheck, word);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        wordcheck[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    //hashes word, then accesses linked list at that value
    int j = hash(wordcheck);
    node *cursor = hashtable[j];
    if (hashtable[j] != NULL)
    {
        //iterates through linked list: cursor pointer starts at head of list and while there is a value, it moves on to the next word in the list
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            //if the word is found, return true
            if (strcmp(cursor->word, wordcheck) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                cursor = cursor->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //opens dictionary file
    FILE *inputfile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //initializes new node pointer and reads words from new file while !EOF
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(inputfile, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        //actually creates and initializes new node( creates space in memory for node using malloc function) and copies word into node while keeping tracking of # of words
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(new_node->word, word);
        }
        //hashes words in node to determine which linked list to use
        int j = hash(new_node->word);
        //initializes node pointer to first bucket in hashtable
        node *head = hashtable[j];
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            //if there is no data in linked list, new_node becomes head of linked list
            hashtable[j] = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            //if data exists, node points to next word in list, then head of linked list points to node pointer
            new_node->next = hashtable[j];
            hashtable[j] = new_node;
        }
    wordcount++;
    fclose(inputfile);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'd suspect load, since "WORDS IN DICTIONARY" is wrong. In the "most basic words" test, the dictionary also contains the word "brown", "brown" would be the first word in the dict, "brown" is not reported as misspelled. The first thing I'd look for would be a misplaced "return true;".

Comment: please post your `load` function

Comment: Load function has been added! So do you think the "return true" at the end of my load function is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I had to change the way the hash function was written inside of the load function and rewrite fclose(inputfile) to be outside of one of the curly braces. All errors gone!